# Erro envolvendo NoneType

Tags: python, lista, fila

Fiz um código bem simples para simular filas em python:

```
lista = []
def a(lista): return lista.append(str(input('Nome: ')).lower().strip())
def b(lista: list):
    if len(lista) == 0:
        print('A lista está vazia, impossível a remoção de item.')
    else:
        av = lista.pop(len(lista)-1)
        print(f'Item {av} foi removido da lista.')
    return lista
dicio = {'i': a, 'p': b, 'x': 'esta parte não importa'}
while True:
    opção = str(input('''O que deseja fazer?
- [i] para inserir um nome na lista.
- [p] para excluir o primeiro item da lista.
- [x] para encerrar o programa.
''')).lower().strip()
    while True:
        if opção in dicio: break
        opção = str(input('Opção inválida, tente novamente:\n')).lower().strip()
    if opção == 'x': break
    lista = dicio[opção](lista)
```

O problema é que após usar algumas vezes aparece esta mensagem de erro:

```
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

ou essa:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: O método `append` de uma `list` não retorna valor, ela modifica a lista "*in-place*". Para retornar a lista, primeiro faça o `append` e **na linha seguinte** retorne a mesma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está aqui:

```
def a(lista): return lista.append(str(input('Nome: ')).lower().strip())
```

O erro ocorre porque  `append` retorna `None`:

```
lista = []
result = lista.append(1)
print(result) # None
```

Ou seja, a função retorna `None`. Então se a função `a` for chamada aqui:

```
lista = dicio[opção](lista)
```

`lista` passará a ser `None` (e não mais a lista original) e aí ocorre o erro indicado (você tenta passar `None` para `len` ou chamar `append` nele).

---

Como ambas as funções modificam a própria lista internamente, não precisaria retornar nada, basta chamá-las e pronto:

```
# funções não precisam retornar
def a(lista):
    lista.append(input('Nome: ').lower().strip())

def b(lista):
    if len(lista) == 0:
        print('A lista está vazia, impossível a remoção de item.')
    else:
        av = lista.pop(len(lista) - 1)
        print(f'Item {av} foi removido da lista.')

lista = []
dicio = {'i': a, 'p': b, 'x': 'esta parte não importa'}
while True:
    while True:
        opção = input('''O que deseja fazer?
- [i] para inserir um nome na lista.
- [p] para excluir o primeiro item da lista.
- [x] para encerrar o programa.
''').lower().strip()
        if opção in dicio: break
        print('Opção inválida, tente novament')
    if opção == 'x': break
    # chama a função, não precisa pegar o retorno
    dicio[opção](lista)
```

Afinal, as funções estão modificando a lista que foi passada e retornando-a em seguida. Mas como é a mesma lista, será que precisa retornar? Faria sentido se as funções retornassem outra lista, mas não é o caso.

Repare também que usar `str(input(...))` é redundante e desnecessário, pois `input` já retorna uma string, então o `str` neste caso pode ser removido.

Outro detalhe é que, se você quer remover o primeiro item da lista, deveria ser `lista.pop(0)`. Da forma que fez, você está removendo o último.